# Loop in cypher, UNWIND or FOREACH (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relation in my neo4j database:

```
(r:RateableEntity)<-[t:TAG]-(h:HashTags)
```

Now I want to have a query that returns a list that includes:

1. A list of `hashtagName` and their frequency in the database as `hashtagCount` and a list of items that related to this hashtags.
   `hashtagName` and `hashtagItems` have `id` label.

I'm receiving the number of `hashtag` and `hashtagItems` from input parameter as variable.

And this is the result that I expected from my cypher query:

```
"hashtagList": [ 
{
  "hashtagName": "hashtagName1",
  "hashtagCount": number of times hashtag has been used in database,
  "hashtagItems": [ list of relevant items for hashtagName1 ]
},
{
  "hashtagName": "hashtagName2",
  "hashtagCount": number of times hashtag has been used in database,
  "hashtagItems": [ list of relevant items for hashtagName2 ]
},
...
]
```

I've written this cypher:

```
MATCH p = (r:RateableEntity)<-[t:TAG]-(h:HashTag)
UNWIND TAIL (NODES(p)) AS hash
WITH COUNT(hash) as Count, h, hash
ORDER BY hash LIMIT 3
WHERE h.tag in hash.tag
MATCH (r:RateableEntity)<-[:TAG]-(h:HashTag)
 RETURN DISTINCT h.tag, r.id, Count
 LIMIT 3
```

But it's returning this result:

```
h.tag       r.id                                  Count
"vanessa"   "cdd14968-404c-41e9-84d5-bf147030a023"  15
"vanessa"   "b7e74f38-44e4-4b7f-b2c4-8301023ffa9b"  15
"vanessa"   "2064d3e4-2995-4202-b178-bb2a6f230ab0"  15
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things to keep in mind:

1. Cypher operators execute for each row.
2. Try not to think of UNWIND as a looping structure. All this does is do a cartesian product of the variables on a row with the elements of a list.

So when you UNWIND a list, you will have a row for each element of the list, along with all the variables that were already present for the row. Then when a subsequent operation happens (like a MATCH or a WITH) that executes for every row, so it seems like a looping structure, but it really isn't.

In any case, UNWIND isn't needed here. For a two-node matched pattern, `tail(nodes(p))` will just be a single-element list containing just the last node. It hasn't changed the number of rows (since the list size is 1), and won't help you here.

This query should work better:

```
MATCH (h:HashTag)
WITH h LIMIT 3 // best to limit early to avoid doing unnecessary work
WITH h, h.tag as hashtagName, size((h)-[:TAG]->()) as hashtagCount, [(h)-[:TAG]->(r:RateableEntity) | r.id] as hashtagItems
WITH h {hashtagName, hashtagCount, hashtagItems} as entry
RETURN collect(entry) as hashtagList
```

EDIT

If you want the top 3 hashtags by size, then you can use the modified query below:

```
MATCH (h:HashTag)
WITH h, size((h)-[:TAG]->()) as hashtagCount
ORDER BY hashtagCount DESC
LIMIT 3
WITH h, hashtagCount, h.tag as hashtagName, [(h)-[:TAG]->(r:RateableEntity) | r.id] as hashtagItems
WITH h {hashtagName, hashtagCount, hashtagItems} as entry
RETURN collect(entry) as hashtagList
```

Comment: Just one more question , If I want to have `ORDER BY` top `size`  , what is your suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for the response, But I just found for the `limit` It's not working as expected but I'm posting another way that I've found on the `neo4j` website

Comment: Hi again, I need to modify this query to return those items related to this `HashTag`, order by `createdDate`(as all those items have `createdDate` property), thanks for help

Comment: Sounds like you should probably create a new question for this, and include what you've tried so far, why it isn't what you need, and an example of sample input and expected output.

Comment: You're right and the link of question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447197/order-by-results-per-row-in-cypher-queryneo4j?noredirect=1#comment97641280_55447197

Comment: @InverseFalcon since you seem to have a good knowledge about what happens behind UNWIND and FOREACH, could you please complete your answer with what happens behind FOREACH. And is the performance cost of UNWIND is likely higher than FOREACH considering UNWIND generates multiple rows while FOREACH does not?

Comment: FOREACH is an iterative processing through each element of a list. It does not increase cardinality the way UNWIND does. Both are useful, and they are useful in similar ways. FOREACH is limited in what it can do since it can only handle write clauses (MERGE, CREATE, DELETE, SET, REMOVE). So when processing list elements that only use write clauses, use FOREACH. When doing anything else, UNWIND. If you want to scope your UNWIND and collect() back up at the end, perform it in a subquery and collect() before the subquery returns.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this for my question, maybe someone else need to know:

```
MATCH (:RateableEntity)<-[:TAG]-(p:HashTag)
RETURN p.tag As Tag, COUNT(p) as Count, [(p)-[:TAG]->(m) | m.id][..3] AS 
RateableEntities ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 3
```

Here is the link for documents on the website:

[limiting-match-results-per-row/](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/)