# 'ORDER BY' results per row in cypher query(Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This question is a follow on to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53714738/9161843)

With 2 answers for that

Now  I need to modify this query to return those items related to this `HashTag`, order by `createdDate`(as all those items have `createdDate` property).

I've written this query:

```
MATCH (r:RateableEntity)<-[:TAG]-(h:HashTag:Featured)
WITH h, COUNT(h) AS Count
  ORDER BY Count DESC
  SKIP 2
  LIMIT 3
WITH h, Count, h.tag as Name,
     [(h)-[:TAG]->(m:RateableEntity {audience: 'world'}) | m][..3] AS Items 
UNWIND Items as row
RETURN row, Name, Count, COLLECT(row.id)
 ORDER BY row.createdDate
```

But the results are:

```
Name          row.id                                  Count
"vanessa"     "cdd14968-404c-41e9-84d5-bf147030a023"  14
"vanessa"     "qwd14968-2344-41e9-84d5-bftt34534566"  14
"vanessa"     "cd14968-404c-41e9-84d5-certt4545455g"  14
"hash"        "b7e74f38-44e4-4b7f-b2c4-8301023ffa9b"  15
"hash"        "edr34334-2995-4202-b178-bb2a6f230ab0"  15
"hash"        "htth5548-404c-41e9-84d5-bf147030a023"  15
"new"         "oljj4968-2344-41e9-84d5-bftt34534566"  3
"new"         "werr4968-404c-41e9-84d5-certt4545455"  3
"new"         "be545b38-44e4-4b7f-b2c4-8301023ffa9b"  3
```

I can see that `count is correct and`skip and `limit` working as I want but here I have 3 rows instead of one row and 3 `id`.
Also `ORDER BY` is not working.

Any idea? ideas appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Actually the result of this query will be nodes and after that, in my code, I'm mapping to this, so still it's not what I want

Comment: Are you sure you are showing the results from that query? For example, where is the `row` value?

Comment: @cybersam Sorry, you are right as I've updated the question, the results will be nodes, not the list

Comment: So, if the problem is in your non-Cypher code, do you really have a neo4j issue?

Comment: @cybersam The reason that I've opened this question is I want to know how can I have the results by the query and as you can see by using code still is not what I want. So I want to know how can I write this query

Comment: You have to show the actual Cypher query results. We cannot tell anything by looking at what your non-Cypher code generated.